# Can't Drag Components To Editor In AEM 6.5

Tags: reactjs, adobe, aem

I have been trying to make my own component in React to be used in AEM. I am currently following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nec_MDPzMYk&t=86s

I am able to build the component and deploy it to my local instance of AEM, but I am unable to drag the component to the editor in AEM. The only components I seem to be able to drag and drop are Container and Text. I've added a public Dropbox folder with three screenshots to help describe my issue: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aiifh6aahf28esu/AADZxqo1apo2NLXquz1ZNhbia?dl=0

I have edited the SPA Page policy in AEM (see first screenshot: “edit template”) to include all of the components listed here, including the new component (Basic Component) that I have added with React (see next screenshot: available components), yet when I go to drag the components to the editor, I can’t do that (see screenshot: editor).
Does anyone see what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In case you will click on 'Drag Component here' and try do add ur component via '+' is your component in the list or not? Might be that you have changed the policy for a different responsive grid.

Also check the error.log, might be there you will find some clues. (http://:/system/console/slinglog/tailer.txt?tail=1000&grep=*&name=%2Flogs%2Ferror.log)

And component should have _cq_dialog or_cq_editConfig. Only in this case AEM allows to add components

Comment: clicking the "+" instead of dragging component shows no components. I feel like I may have changed the policy by accident. I checked the error.log and didn't notice any issues. My components all have a "cq_dialog" or "_cq_editConfig" in their files. How can I view policies and update them? Or revert back to default policies (before I made any edits)? Is there a way to do this?